# 3D implementation of boxes overlapping each other

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

How do you find whether two boxes are overlapping each other?
I need help with a 3D implementation of it.

Considering

- Boxes have random length, width
- The boxes can have some of the same endpoints. (So basically, they have to overlap within each other).
- Oriented with the co-ordinate lines

Comment: are the boxes oriented along the coordinate lines?

Comment: Indeed they are oriented along the coordinate lines

Comment: Just like in 2D, adding the same tests on Z.

Comment: Could you give me a condition example? Remember, the boxes and have some of the same endpoints. @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2):

An N-dimensional box oriented along coordinate axes is a product of N segments `[l_i;h_i]` for `i=1..N`.

Two such boxes overlap iff (if and only if) the corresponding segments overlap in *each* dimension.

Two line segments `[a;b]` and `[c;d]` are disjoint iff `a>d || c>b`, IOW, they intersect iff `a<=b && c<=b`.

If you are interested in open boxes `(a;b)` instead of `[a;b]`, replace `>` with `>=` and `<=` with `<`.